# ArrayList automatically adding null items

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, null

---

Hello everyone.
I'm making a vocabulary App, in which I need to create a 
`List<String>` (or ArrayList). To do so, I've created the following piece of code (just an example):

```java
List<String> tempSOLUTION = new ArrayList<String>();
String temp = "abc123";
tempSOLUTION.add(temp);
```

I've also tried the following:

```java
tempSOLUTION.add(new String(temp));
```

Both of them add the item to the list, but while debugging, I find that it's array has 12 objects, which are the following:

```java
[abc123, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

My problem is that I cannot have those null items, as this new list is the key on a `HashableMap<String>`, so any change will cause an exception, as the key would NOT exist.

Screenshot of the list (tempSOLUTION) details using the debugger: http://www.pabloarteaga.es/stackoverflow.jpg

How can I add an item to the list without creating all those null items?

After having searched, I found an answer on how to remove these null items, which is:

```java
tempSOLUTION.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

But it does not work for my purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably looking at its internal array with the debugger.  That doesn't matter; it's just an implementation detail.

What matters is what's visible through its public API.  In other words, what calls to `size()` (and so on) tell you.  (And if that doesn't return `1` in your code example, then something weird is going on!)

Comment: Thank you very much, solved my question :)

Will accept it as an answer as soon as the system allows me to.

Answer (score 6):

From your screenshot it is clear that what is exactly

```
[abc123, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

is not the `ArrayList` itself but its member variable `objectData` which happens to be the internal buffer of the `ArrayList` (where it actually stores elements you add to it).

This buffer has a greater size than the actual size of the `ArrayList` because otherwise, every time that you add a new element, the whole `objectData` should be reallocated as a larger array and all elements copied, but this is surely expensive.

Follow Oli's advice, just ignore the implementation details and trust only the interface.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Didn't know it was that way.
So, if my array was larger than 12 items, that buffer would be even bigger?

Sorry for not voting up, but I don't have enough rep.